# objective-c "add buttons automatically"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i need any kind of idea. 
this is the problem. i am parsing a xml file which contains the url of an image, name of buttons, url for link to another UIwebview or view, etc... those are the important. what i need is; if a read a name of the button, on the screen must to add a new button automatically with its own image and link. i mean if in the xml i have 6 tags with the information mentioned previously, in the screen must to have 6 buttons with image and link. if in the xml exists more they must exist in the screen or uiwebview too.

i appreciate your help or ideas!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can begin by using the `NSXMLParser` to parse the XML and obtain the properties for your buttons.

[NSXMLParser Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Once you know how many tags you need, you can iterate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numTags; i++) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // The tag is so when clicked, you can determine which one was pressed
    // It would help to have your links stored in an NSArray, so you can pull
    // them out by index.
    button.tag = i; 
    [button setTitle:buttonName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openButtonLink:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = ...; // How do you want your buttons laid out?
    [someView addSubview:button];
}
```

I would also recommend checking out the class reference for `UIButton`:

[UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)